# Client live update with socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm having troubles chosing the best design for my app.
I'm coding a mobile app and I need to get pictures from my server, and display them using their gps coordinates attributes on a google map using markers.

So, normally I'd just GET them from my api using a simple `GET /pictures`, but then I thought of a better (and maybe more elegant) way to do it. I wanted to use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) for live updating the pictures, because when I get the pictures from the API, I don't get all of them, I only take the ones that are where the client looks on the map (using google maps' `getBounds()`), so GETting /pictures everytime the user changes where he looks seemed a little bit slow.
Initially, I used google maps' idle event to GET the pictures in an area.

What I would like to do now, is a live updating map using websockets, but I can't understand how I would implement it in my app. Here's the problem:
`user1` gets the pictures in an area. He gets the pictures, and they are drawn on the map using markers. Ok.
`user2` creates a picture, in the area `user1` looks. Or even more generally: `user2` makes an action on a picture `user1` is looking (liking it, deleting it, creating a new one, whatever)

Now, how does `user1` know that an action has been taken? The server could broadcast an emit, but then what? What about other users that aren't looking at the picture?
I just don't get how to be synchronous with the server: deleting a marker when the picture is deleted, incrementing a number when a picture gets a like. I don't get it, and I want to know because I think it would be a very good time to make a real time app, or maybe I'm forcing it and I should stick to HTTP.

I've thought of using `setInterval` on the client and asking for the pictures (with fresh informations on it) but I don't know if it's the cleanest way to do it.

Thank you for your time

Comment: https://www.codetutorial.io/laravel-5-and-socket-io-tutorial/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still broadcast an emit using socket.io and that would be enough for users who are currently looking at the same area; but you also need to store this new information somewhere (e.g. Database) for users who are not currently looking at the same area, so that when they go to that area they would get the most up to date information from the server/database.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, sorry for this "dump-looking" question but how would that differ from a simple HTTP schema ? Speed ?

Comment: And also, I'd like to know one more thing: when I receive the broadcast as a user, I just don't get how to handle it. I mean imagine a user likes a picture, he emits to the server, the server stores the like in database, then I don't understand what the server should broadcast for the currently looking users... The new count of likes? But isn't that huge to broadcast this everytime an action is taken on a picture?  
Thank you very much anyway you almost resoved my issue

Comment: @Jhun "Socket.IO is an event-based bi-directional communication layer for realtime web applications, built atop Engine.IO. It abstracts many transports, including AJAX long-polling and WebSockets, into a single API. It allows developers to send and receive data without worrying about cross-browser compatibility.
" - [Fionn Kelleher](https://nodesource.com/blog/understanding-socketio/)

Comment: @Jhun if you want updates shown to users in realtime then this is a very good way to start, and yes you can send the new number of likes.

Comment: All right I think I'll do that. One last question I'm just wondering about, won't it present some performance issues when I'll have a lot of simultaneous clients? Everytime a client emits, making a broadcast to all other clients, etc.

Comment: @Jhun it all depends on the specs of your server. Take a look at [this](http://drewww.github.io/socket.io-benchmarking/), it might be what you're looking for.